# How do I copy files from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do I copy files from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance?
Both are windows instances and firewall protected.

cmd, curl or powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/?nc1=h_ls) to transfer files to an Amazon S3 bucket from the first EC2 and then back to the other EC2.